# Не вызывается async функция

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

JS(React native) только изучаю после JAVA, не пойму понять в чем фишка и почему не вызывается функция async внутри функции? Где моя ошибка?

```
    callAfterFetch(body): function{
    let responceJson = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log("BODY=" + responceJson.error);
    if (responceJson.error === '0'){
        this.setState({
            token: responceJson.userKey,
            address: responceJson.address,
        })
        this.writeTokenToLocalStorage()
    //  this.writeTokenToLocalStorage(body.userKey, body.address);
    }
}


writeTokenToLocalStorage(): function {
    console.log("BODY2=" + this.state.token)
/* надо вызвать*/   
async () => {
            console.log("BODY22=" + this.state.token);
            try {
                await AsyncStorage.setItem(MyConstants.TOKEN, this.state.token)
                await AsyncStorage.setItem(MyConstants.ADDRESS, this.state.address)
                console.log("DONEWRITE=" + this.state.token + "|" + this.state.address)
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("error_writeTokenToLocalStorage=" + error)
            }
        }
}
```

Судя по логам, выполнения прерывается после

```
   console.log("BODY2=" + this.state.token)
```

Comment: Ошибка в том, что вы функцию только объявили, но не вызвали

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Что бы вызвать функцию, ее надо... вызвать!

Попробуйте [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/IIFE)

```
writeTokenToLocalStorage(): function {
  console.log("BODY2=" + this.state.token)
  /* надо вызвать*/
  (async() => {
    console.log("BODY22=" + this.state.token);
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(MyConstants.TOKEN, this.state.token)
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(MyConstants.ADDRESS, this.state.address)
      console.log("DONEWRITE=" + this.state.token + "|" + this.state.address)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error_writeTokenToLocalStorage=" + error)
    }
  })();
}
```